# Change title in wordpress search query

Tags: wordpress, search, wordpress-hook

I've got problem with WordPress search.

I want to get the same results in WP search when i enter for eg. word "rosol" and "rosół".

```
function change($tekst)
   {
   $wynik = strtr($tekst, 'ĘÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃęóąśłżźćń', 'EOASLZZCNeoaslzzcn');
   return($wynik);
}
```

but i try and can't find `filter/hook` to implode my function. With which `filter/hook` i could do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','change');
```

If this is only to be applied to searches,  you should also add `if ($tekst->is_search){}`